# Seem to have lost 4 Silver badges and 10 Bronze badges

Tags: support, badges, merge-accounts, tag-badges

I updated my email on SO, and for some reason now, I've lost 4 silver badges and 10 bronze badges. Not sure what is going on here, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: did you merge accounts? badges are recalculated when merging, which is one of the few instances where you can lose a badge if you no longer meet the criteria

Comment: Your [tags tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1283845/blaine?tab=tags) is empty; this usually indicates you initiated an account merge by changing email..

Comment: I did change my email. How can I recover those badges?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your account history shows that the email change caused your account to be automatically merged into an older one. This causes all badges from the newer account (which got merged) to cease to exist. If you still qualify for them, they will be automatically awarded to you again whenever the respective badge processes run next. Many of them have already been given back to you, but some will take a while. Noteably tag badges, which are only awarded when the tag scores are updated at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: That would make sense! Thank you.

Comment: *If* the tag scores are updated at 03:00. That script times out more often than not in Stack Overflow.

Comment: For me it took about 5 min until all badges were reassigned. I guess I was lucky. :)